# MySQL 5.1.39 SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error

I have made an upgrade for my MySQL Server to 5.1.39 and now when I run SQL scripts (which had worked previously) - it throws error. I have checked syntax many times and I couldn't find any incompatible code parts. Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Error message

> Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE FUNCTION clean_dymmy_table (dummy_name VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS V' at line 3:

SQL code:

```
 /*DELIMITER //*/
 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS clean_dymmy_table;
 CREATE FUNCTION clean_dymmy_table (dummy_name VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
 DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
    DECLARE temp_val VARCHAR(255);
    SET temp_val = dummy_name;

    -- Test
    SET temp_val = REPLACE(temp_val, 'Tmp ', '');
    SET temp_val = REPLACE(temp_val, ' TmP', '');
    SET temp_val = REPLACE(temp_val, 'TMP ', '');
    SET temp_val = REPLACE(temp_val, ' TMP', '');
    SET temp_val = REPLACE(temp_val, ' tmp', '');

    RETURN dummy_name;
 END/*//*/
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match the provided SQL code.

Comment: Do you reckon this has anything to do with it? http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46429

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hunch: There seems to be a MySQL Bug in the 5.1.x line pertaining to `DELIMITER` that may be biting you here:

- [#46429](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46429) use DELIMITER command in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlScript

Though that heavily depends on how you're calling it, given [**cwallenpoole**'s response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505030/mysql-5-1-39-sql-syntax-error/6505154#6505154), your symptom does suggest it may well be that bug, given your MySQL version. Is upgrading a possibility for you?

Comment: Better way is not to upgrade. Do you have any suggestion, how can I refactor SQL code to get rid of DELIMITER statement in the code?

Comment: I've never worked with SQL procedures, unfortunately. But if I understand the bug correctly, you should be able to use `DELIMITER` by calling the code from the mysql *client*. Check out the comment by **Valeriy Kravchuk** in that link.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you removed the DELIMITER part, but when I add that back in, it runs fine:

```
DELIMITER // -- you have to change what MySQL expects between commands
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS clean_dymmy_table // -- tell it a new command's coming
CREATE FUNCTION clean_dymmy_table (dummy_name VARCHAR(255)) 
                                   RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    -- now this can be parsed as part of the current command.
    DECLARE temp_val VARCHAR(255); 
    SET temp_val = dummy_name;

    -- Test
    RETURN dummy_name;
END
// -- Now you're done with that command.
-- go back to semi-colons, because otherwise life is too zany for me.
DELIMITER ;
```

(This was in 5.1.54... but I don't think that should matter)

Comment: I have changed code to this: `DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS clean_dymmy_table //
CREATE FUNCTION clean_dymmy_table (dummy_name VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE temp_val VARCHAR(255);
    SET temp_val = dummy_name;

    RETURN temp_val;
END
//
DELIMITER ;` But now it throws same error `Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS clean_dymmy_table //
CREATE FUNCTION c' at line 1`

Comment: What happens if you literally copy and paste the above into something which will evaluate a script? (In MySQL browser this will be under scripts, it won't be a regular query)